# Passing a reference to a pointer to pointer of type void

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have a function that accepts a reference to void**.

```
bool boExecute(void**& vOutParameter);
```

I tried to write some value in vOutParameter, but when I checked it in the main(), the value was not written.

In this case, what does & referencing to? Is it a reference to a pointer or a reference to a pointer to pointer?

Inside boExecute, I add it like this:

```
bool boExecute(void**& vOutParameter)
{
    Struct_Type* Out = new Struct_Type[4];
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(&(Out[i]), Referenced_Struct[i], sizeof(Struct_Type));
    }
    *vOutParameter = reinterpret_cast<void*>Out;
    Out = null;
    return true;
}
```

Referenced_Struct is of type Struct_Type**, which had two members, int32_val and int64_val.

Contents of main:

```
void main(void)
{
   void **test;
   boExecute(test);
   Struct_Type** temp = reinterpret_cast<Struct_Type**>(test);
   Struct_Type* temp1 = *temp;
   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
   {
       printf("%d, %d", temp1[i].int32_val, temp1[i].int64_val);
   }
}
```

Is there something wrong in what I'm doing?
When I changed *vOutParameter, the contents of *vOutParameter should be updated when it goes out of the function, right?

Comment: `vOutParameter = ...` would modify the pointer you passed from `main()` (and chose for whatever reason not to include in your question). You said, "I have a function that accepts a `void*`" - no, that function accepts a reference to a `void**`. They're night-and-day different.

Comment: But I did not change the vOutParameter. I only change the reference which is *vOutParameter. Does this mean that whatever *vOutParameter contains, it get lost after the function call?

Comment: "I did not change the `vOutParameter`..." - exactly. That would be why the pointer we *still* can't see in the call from `main()` didn't change. Why do you think you need a  `void**&` for this? I think you can get away with simply `void**` or `void*&`, but its impossible to say without know the the expectations of the call from `main()`. The answer to the posted question, what does & referencing to, it is a reference to pointer-to-pointer-to-`void`.

Comment: The problem might be in the call to `memcpy`, try changing `sizeof(Struct_Type*)` to `sizeof(Struct_Type)`.

Comment: Use structure assignment instead of `memcpy`, if the type is not trivially copyable then memcpy causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the contents of the main().

Answer (score 5):

> Is there something wrong in what I'm doing?

You should rewrite the function actually using C++, instead of weird C semantic with unnecessary boolean return values for errors and out parameters:

```
template<typename It>
std::vector<Struct_type> boExecute(It Reference_begin, It Reference_end)
{
    std::vector<Struct_type> Out;
    std::copy(Reference_begin, Reference_end, std::back_inserter(Out));
    return Out;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04a8e192b215ad3c)</kbd>

Notice that there's no performance issue in returning the *whole* vector because of RVO (Return Value Optimization). So you can sleep knowing that your memory is safe.

---

> In this case, what does & referencing to? Is it a reference to a pointer or a reference to a pointer to pointer?

In general `T&` is a reference to `T`. Which means that `void**&` is a reference to a `void**` which is a pointer to pointer to `void`.

Comment: Note that this ultimately can reduce to simply `return std::vector<Struct_type>(begin,end);`, and thusly brings into question the necessity for the function in the first place.